# How to get the first clock out time and second clock in time for each user SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that i'm trying to get a users break time.  I thought I could just use the first punch out time, and the Second punch in time, and use the date difference to break it out per employee.  However, what it's doing is grabbing the FIRST to punch out for lunch, and the LAST user to punch out for the day.  How would I get it to list each employees break time by employee.  Below is my query:

```
SELECT lEmployeeID,
       DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS Break_Time
FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
WHERE (TotalHours >= 0)
AND   (DID IS NOT NULL)
OR    (DID IS NOT NULL)
AND   (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY lEmployeeID
```

Comment: A truly useful answer hinges on more information about your database schema.  What does a single row contain?  Are you trying to get break times for all users or just one?  Do you need to see break times for just "today" or for some date or range of dates in the past?

Comment: presumably a break would be a clock in/out that occurs DURING the day, so you'd need to determine which clock in/outs represent the actual morning arrival/afternoon departure, EXCLUDE those particular events, then use the rest of the in/out events during the day as the breaks.

Comment: I'm using a date range.  Break time for all users.  The dttimein and dttimeout house when a user punches in and out.  So I punch in at 8 punch out at 12 punch in at1230 punch out at 5.  I worked 8.5 hours and took a 30 min break

Comment: Assuming that an employee only takes one break, your query should just do it per employee. You need to group by employeeId and date ie. date(Timein) to get the results for each day. Also, convert the datetime to a 24 hr. format before doing datefiff - DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(convert(datetime,dtTimeOut,9)), MAX(convert(datetime,dtTimeIn,9)))

Comment: I think we need to see that table valued function, and a sample of what it returns.

Comment: FYI - your where clause appears to be wrong. You say "(TotalHours >=0) And (DID IS NOT NULL) OR (DID IS NOT NULL) And (dtTimeOut IS NULL). That will return records for everything that satisfies JUST the "OR (DID IS NOT NULL)" since you don't have any groupings on the parenthesis.

Comment: Please create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ to get better help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be far from the most efficient method of doing this, but with some of my own test data, I was able to get the minutes of each break using a series of date data--this would break if the range of dates left within the range of a single day. Hopefully this might inspire someone to come up with a better way...

Output:
30
60

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(num INT PRIMARY KEY, activity DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @test(num, activity)
VALUES(77, '2014-01-10 08:00:00'),
(34, '2014-01-10 12:00:00'), (1000, '2014-01-10 12:30:00'), (1, '2014-01-10 18:00:00')
, (34345, '2014-01-10 14:00:00'), (2334, '2014-01-10 15:00:00');


SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Ordered.activity, offs.offActivity)
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        activity
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY activity) AS Iteration, num, activity 
        FROM 
            @test As iD1
    ) AS Rowed
    WHERE
        Rowed.iteration % 2 = 0
) AS Ordered
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        activity as offActivity
    FROM
        @test iD
    WHERE
        iD.activity > Ordered.activity
    ORDER BY 
        activity
) As Offs
```